# Syntax Error in Precompilled WebRTC Library

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, include, webrtc

I downloaded the precompiled lib for windows x64 from https://sourcey.com/precompiled-webrtc-libraries. I linked against the .lib and included the header files. Now when I #include the peerconnectioninterface.h header I get over 100 syntax errors coming from that include.

Here is the Error output.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E1574   static assertion failed with ".data() and .size() are private"  WebRTC_CPP  C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\WebRTC_CPP\WebRTC_CPP\libs\WebRTC\x64\include\webrtc\rtc_base\type_traits.h  70  
Error   C2589   '(': illegal token on right side of '::'    WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\rtc_base\copyonwritebuffer.h    187 
Warning C4003   not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\media\base\videosourceinterface.h   30  
Warning C4003   not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\media\base\videosourceinterface.h   38  
Error   C2589   '(': illegal token on right side of '::'    WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\media\base\videosourceinterface.h   30  
Error   C2062   type 'unknown-type' unexpected  WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\media\base\videosourceinterface.h   30  
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\media\base\videosourceinterface.h   30  
Error   C2589   '(': illegal token on right side of '::'    WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\media\base\videosourceinterface.h   38  
Error   C2062   type 'unknown-type' unexpected  WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\media\base\videosourceinterface.h   38  
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\media\base\videosourceinterface.h   38  
Error   C4996   '_vsnwprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _vsnwprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\rtc_base\stringutils.h  96  
Warning C4003   not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'min'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\rtc_base\timeutils.h    138 
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\rtc_base\timeutils.h    138 
Error   C2334   unexpected token(s) preceding ':'; skipping apparent function body  WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\rtc_base\timeutils.h    138 
Warning C4003   not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\rtc_base\timeutils.h    139 
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ')' before ';'    WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\rtc_base\timeutils.h    154 
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\rtc_base\timeutils.h    154 
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\rtc_base\timeutils.h    154 
Error   C2059   syntax error: 'namespace'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\rtc_base\messagequeue.h 34  
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '{'    WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\rtc_base\messagequeue.h 34  
Error   C2614   'rtc::IntervalRange': illegal member initialization: 'min_' is not a base or member WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\rtc_base\timeutils.h    133 
Error   C2614   'rtc::IntervalRange': illegal member initialization: 'max_' is not a base or member WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\rtc_base\timeutils.h    133 
Error   C2614   'rtc::IntervalRange': illegal member initialization: 'min_' is not a base or member WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\rtc_base\timeutils.h    134 
Error   C2614   'rtc::IntervalRange': illegal member initialization: 'max_' is not a base or member WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\rtc_base\timeutils.h    134 
Error   C2447   '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\rtc_base\messagequeue.h 34  
Error   C2079   'rtc::rtc::_SendMessage::msg' uses undefined struct 'rtc::Message'  WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\rtc_base\thread.h   85  
Error   C2504   'rtc::MessageQueue': base class undefined   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\rtc_base\thread.h   103 
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'MessageData'  WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\rtc_base\thread.h   167 
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'MessageList'  WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\rtc_base\thread.h   187 
Error   C3668   'rtc::rtc::Thread::~Thread': method with override specifier 'override' did not override any base class methods  WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\rtc_base\thread.h   119 
Error   C3668   'rtc::rtc::Thread::Clear': method with override specifier 'override' did not override any base class methods    WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\rtc_base\thread.h   185 
Error   C3668   'rtc::rtc::Thread::ReceiveSends': method with override specifier 'override' did not override any base class methods WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\rtc_base\thread.h   188 
Error   C2065   'MQID_ANY': undeclared identifier   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\rtc_base\thread.h   186 
Error   C2039   'RefCountInterface': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc'  WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  60  
Error   C2039   'RefCountInterface': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc'  WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  80  
Error   C2039   'VideoSourceInterface': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  121 
Error   C2955   'rtc::VideoSourceInterface': use of class template requires template argument list  WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  121 
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ',' before '<'    WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  121 
Error   C2039   'Optional': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  141 
Error   C2059   syntax error: '<'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  141 
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  141 
Error   C2039   'VideoSourceInterface': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  161 
Error   C2955   'rtc::VideoSourceInterface': use of class template requires template argument list  WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  161 
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ',' before '<'    WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  161 
Error   C2039   'VideoSinkInterface': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc' WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  170 
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ')' before '<'    WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  170 
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '<'    WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  170 
Error   C2059   syntax error: '<'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  170 
Error   C2039   'VideoSinkWants': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc' WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  171 
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  171 
Error   C2334   unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body  WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  171 
Error   C2039   'VideoSinkInterface': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc' WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  172 
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ')' before '<'    WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  172 
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '<'    WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  172 
Error   C2059   syntax error: '<'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  172 
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  172 
Error   C2334   unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body  WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  172 
Error   C2039   'RefCountInterface': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc'  WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  227 
Error   C2039   'scoped_refptr': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc'  WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  279 
Error   C2059   syntax error: '<'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  279 
Error   C2334   unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body  WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  279 
Error   C2039   'scoped_refptr': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc'  WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  287 
Error   C2947   expecting '>' to terminate template-argument-list, found '<'    WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  287 
Error   C3203   'scoped_refptr': unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter '_Ty', expected a real type   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  287 
Error   C2371   'rtc::webrtc::AudioTrackInterface': redefinition; different basic types WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  287 
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '>'    WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  287 
Error   C2059   syntax error: '>'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  287 
Error   C2039   'scoped_refptr': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc'  WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  289 
Error   C2947   expecting '>' to terminate template-argument-list, found '<'    WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  289 
Error   C3203   'scoped_refptr': unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter '_Ty', expected a real type   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  289 
Error   C2371   'rtc::webrtc::VideoTrackInterface': redefinition; different basic types WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  289 
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '>'    WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  289 
Error   C2059   syntax error: '>'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  289 
Error   C2039   'RefCountInterface': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc'  WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  300 
Error   C3646   'GetAudioTracks': unknown override specifier    WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  305 
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  305 
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  305 
Error   C3646   'GetVideoTracks': unknown override specifier    WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  306 
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  306 
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  306 
Error   C2039   'scoped_refptr': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc'  WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  307 
Error   C2059   syntax error: '<'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  307 
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  308 
Error   C2039   'scoped_refptr': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc'  WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  309 
Error   C2059   syntax error: '<'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  309 
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\mediastreaminterface.h  310 
Error   C2039   'RefCountInterface': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc'  WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\dtmfsenderinterface.h   38  
Error   C2039   'RefCountInterface': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc'  WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\jsep.h  151 
Error   C2039   'RefCountInterface': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc'  WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\jsep.h  164 
Error   C2039   'MessageData': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc'    WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\proxy.h 122 
Error   C2504   'MessageData': base class undefined WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\proxy.h 122 
Error   C2039   'MessageHandler': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc' WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\proxy.h 123 
Error   C2039   'MessageHandler': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc' WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\proxy.h 125 
Error   C2039   'Location': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\proxy.h 129 
Error   C2039   'Message': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc'    WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\proxy.h 140 
Error   C2039   'Event': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc'  WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\proxy.h 144 
Error   C2039   'MessageHandler': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc' WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\proxy.h 145 
Error   C2039   'Event': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc'  WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\proxy.h 133 
Error   C2039   'Post': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc::Thread'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\proxy.h 134 
Error   C3083   'Event': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type    WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\proxy.h 135 
Error   C2039   'kForever': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\proxy.h 135 
Error   C2065   'kForever': undeclared identifier   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\proxy.h 135 
Error   C2039   'Message': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc'    WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\proxy.h 151 
Error   C2504   'rtc::Message': base class undefined    WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\proxy.h 151 
Error   C2039   'MessageHandler': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc' WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\proxy.h 152 
Error   C2039   'Location': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc'   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\proxy.h 157 
Error   C2039   'Message': is not a member of 'rtc::rtc'    WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\proxy.h 163 
Error   C1003   error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation   WebRTC_CPP  c:\users\sebastian\desktop\webrtc_cpp\webrtc_cpp\libs\webrtc\x64\include\webrtc\api\proxy.h 163
```

Here is what my Code looks like.

```
#ifndef PEER_CONNECTION_HPP

# define PEER_CONNECTION_HPP

#define WEBRTC_WIN

#include "webrtc/api/peerconnectioninterface.h"

class PeerConnection
{
};

#endif
```

I am wondering how there can be syntax errors in the header files. This should not be the case. In case anyone knows better let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it.

You have to `#define NOMINMAX` aswell. Thanks to this post
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/discuss-webrtc/syntax$20error%7Csort:date/discuss-webrtc/eBIhDE0c0Ac/WrAZGdabAAAJ

Comment: You are a legend